How do you read each password protected excels in one folder and extract certain columns from each spreadsheets?
Per title, I have multiple weekly reports that have the exact same format/columns, and I want to extract all the rows and some columns and make an annually report. The filename for each spreadsheets doesn't really have a pattern to follow. But, the password for all excels is the same. I'm wondering if there's a way to just ask R to open one file by the other and pull the rows and certain columns. I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance!!
I have been able to read a single password protected file using xl.read.file from excel package.
Report <- xl.read.file(path = ".xlsx", password = "pw")

I just added some comments on accessing a single excel file. I haven't tried anything for reading in the whole folder because unsure where to start. Thanks.

Why not get a list of the files with e. g. dir('your_folder', pattern = '\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE) and apply a custom function to each list item?
